# Pass a class member from a sub to another

Tags: excel, vba, class

It's a simple question with an easy workaround, but it would make my code simpler if there is a solution.

My actual code, which works, is of this type:

```
Sub test()

If Condition Then

    Set classmember = New Class1
    *Instructions to execute with classmember*

    Else: classmember = New class2
    *Instructions to execute with classmember*

End If

End Sub
```

I'd like to excute the instructions in a separate sub. If I do, my classmember is set back to variant when I switch to the other sub, even with static.
I tried to execute a function(classmember) to pass the classmember, the object doesn't support the method.

It works when I declare it public, but it's a temporary variable to create dictionary entries. Adding an entry to the dictionary and removing the item also works, but I'm looking for a solution in the general case.

If there is none, I guess a public dictionary/collection for all the temp variables would be an acceptable solution ?

Real code below :

```
Sub peupler_dictionnaire_configs()

For iLigneAnnuaireWs = 3 To 22          '

    Select Case WsCfg.Cells(iLigneAnnuaireWs, 11)

        Case "nautique"                 

        Set CfgTemp as New Cfg_Naut  'temp class member to populate the DictCfg dictionary

     End Select

Cfgtemp.AdresseCfg(1, 1) = WsCfg.Cells(iLigneAnnuaireWs, 4).Value
Cfgtemp.AdresseCfg(1, 2) = WsCfg.Cells(iLigneAnnuaireWs, 5).Value
Cfgtemp.AdresseCfg(2, 1) = WsCfg.Cells(iLigneAnnuaireWs, 6).Value
Cfgtemp.AdresseCfg(2, 2) = WsCfg.Cells(iLigneAnnuaireWs, 7).Value

Cfgtemp.Read_Cfg

'add entry to dictionary
 DictCfg.Add WsCfg.Cells(iLigneAnnuaireWs, 1), Cfgtemp

'reset of the temp class member
 Set CfgNautTemp = Nothing



Next iLigneAnnuaireWs

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the reason for using the same variable in the `if` and the `else` paths? If you had two different variables, you could just `dim` them as their respective classes; I think that would be the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: There are a few class with a common part (they have an array of worksheet adresses, and an array of datas) and a non common part (the properties are different).
The idea would be to get the common part (ie the datas) from the sheet no matter the class. 1) Set variable 2) block if/end-if to determine the class 3) applies the instruction to the class object and add an entry to the dictionary no matter the class. I want to avoid having the instructions in each if/case (as it is the case in my real code. Woops, old version : corrected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a case for inheritance.

You'll want a parent level interface class, which has all the common functions from `Class1` and `Class2`; let's call it `ParentClass`.

As an example, let's say you've got a single common function, which takes no arguments, and returns a string.

Class `ParentClass` would have this code:

```
Function testFunction() As String
End Function
```

Class `Class1` would then implement `ParentClass`, and all its functions (in addition to whatever functions are specific to `Class1`. To implement a function, you prefix it with the name of the parent class.

So, the code for class `Class1` could look like this:

```
Implements ParentClass

Function ParentClass_testFunction() As String
    ParentClass_testFunction = "Hello world! I'm the first child!"
End Function
```

The code for `Class2` could look like this:

```
Implements ParentClass

Function ParentClass_testFunction() As String
    ParentClass_testFunction = "Hello world! I'm the second child!"
End Function
```

In your main code, you would `dim` your variable as a `ParentClass`, and when you actually create an instance, you would use your child classes.

For example, this code first prints "Hello world! I'm the first child!", then "Hello world! I'm the second child!".

```
Dim x As ParentClass

Set x = New Class1
MsgBox x.testFunction

Set x = New Class2
MsgBox x.testFunction
```

Using a `Dim` statement to create the variable is the key here; if you don't `dim` it, it's automatically created as a `variant`, and that's what you'll see in any functions that you pass it to.

Comment: I had no idea about inheritances, that will greatly simplify my code. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer !